# How to set quota on a shared folder with respect to a user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-folders, quota

I have a shared folder created on a volume , and how do I set quota on that shared folder with respect to that user , the problem here is that It's a shared folder and the user has just access to the shared folder .

Now is there a way to set quota on the shared folder with respect to the user ? 
I'm using the quota utility

Answer (score 0):

Using **file server resource manager** you can set a quota on the folder. There is no specific option to link the quota to a specific user. The quota on the folder will be for all users.

Comment: I want it on linux